# printing only required data from session array in th e required format and a

Tags: php, mysql, session

i want to bill the records stored in the session by avoiding unwanted data  i am using `foreach` loop or `print_r` to print but it is giving conventional structure

```
<?php
$b = print_r(array_values ($_SESSION), true);
echo $b.'<br/>';
?>


 <?php
 foreach ($_SESSION as $key => &$value) {
 $array[] = $value;
 echo $value;
}
?>
```

now    `$value` is giving the only the data and `$b` is giving data along with keys but i want to print the data in form of bill i stored different required fields in different session arrays using
           `array_push($_SESSION['a1'],$conum);`
i want to print in form of html table independent of number values stored in the session array guys please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Just store your data in `$_SESSION['my_data']`, i.e `array_push($_SESSION['my_data']['a1'], $conum);` then you can print it like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['my_data'] as $key => $value) {
 echo "{$key} => {$value}";
}
```

Comment: i want print in the required format like table in html using <td> but it giving only the fixed alignment

Comment: Have you use some template system like smarty or sth like that? Or maybe you're printing it directly as html?

Comment: i m using it directly

Answer (score 0):

So do it in this way:

```
 echo '<table>';

foreach ($_SESSION['my_data'] as $key => $value) {
 echo "<tr><td>{$key}</td><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
}

echo '</table>';
```